# How to add "addTarget:action:forControlEvents" on custom SpinnerField : NSObject

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there any possibility of adding a method addTarget to the custom SpinnerField : NSObject ? Because I'm getting No visible @interface for 'CustomField' declares the selector 'addTarget:action:forControlEvents

Comment: Use `UIControl` as base class instead of `NSObject` to get `addTarget:action:forControlEvents`.

Comment: You should look into a tutorial on UIGestureRecognizer, it is likely what you want to be using for what you're trying to accomplish.